# How to relations Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Sorry, I am a beginner with the yii web framework

I want to know how to relate between 2 tables.

Here,

Assume, I have 2 tables

first table = Member(id, username, password)

second table = Product(id, member_id, product_name, product_detail)

and I have form post product when I already post form I want to show member_id that

login.

Here this simple code's me

In model/Member.php

```
<?php
class Member extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function model($c = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($c);
    }

    public function tableName(){
        return "members";
    }



}
```

?>

In model/Product.php

```
<?php
class Product extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function model($c = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($c);
    }

    public function tableName() {
        return "products";          
    }

    public function relations() {
        return array(
            "members" => array(self::BELONGS_TO, "Member", "members_id")
        );
    }
}
```

?>

How to write code in controller,script.js and show value on view?

Comment: [RTM](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship): add a `relations` method to the `Member` class, with a `HAS_MANY` or `HAS_ONE` relation. As far as the js and controller code is concerned: That _really_ is your job... SO isn't a code-generator

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//Get product by primary key.

$product_id = 20;
$data = Product::model()->findByPk($product_id);//SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = 20;

//get username and password from table member.
$username = $data->members->username;
$password = $data->members->password;
//"members" is the alias from function relations() in your model Product
//I mean this "members" => array(self::BELONGS_TO, "Member", "members_id")

//and like this select fields from "producto"
$product_name = $data->product_name;
$product_detail = $data->product_detail;
```